# Proving the Continuity of Integration (Royden)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be integrable on $E$.

if $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an ascending countable collection of measurable subsets of $E$, then:

$\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n} f = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_n} f$

Also, if if $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a descending countable collection of measurable subsets of $E$, then:

$\int_{\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n} f = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_n} f$

I've been trying to prove this for awhile now and seem to have gotten stuck in tunnel vision. I would really appreciate a fresh perspective! Also, i'm pretty bad at this stuff, so the more details / perspectives the better! Thanks!

Comment: since you post here your homework,at least change the usual poem with the tunnel vision...;p ..Be more creative.

Comment: it's true though, i did most of my HW myself, stack xchange is a last resort >.< these r the ones I got stuck on.

Comment: Did  you miss some hypothesis?

Comment: added hypothesis, sry good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assume that $f$ is integrable on $E$:**
\begin{align*}
\int_{\bigcup_{n}E_{n}}f=\int f\chi_{\bigcup_{n}E_{n}},
\end{align*}
and $f\chi_{E_{n}}\uparrow f\chi_{\bigcup_{n}E_{n}}$ and apply Monotone Convergence Theorem. Of course, you need to split $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$ and assuming first that $f$ is nonnegative.

$f\chi_{E_{n}}\downarrow f\chi_{\bigcap_{n}E_{n}}$ and use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem for the other one.

\begin{align*}
\int_{\bigcup_{n}E_{n}}f&=\int_{\bigcup_{n}E_{n}}f^{+}-\int_{\bigcup_{n}E_{n}}f^{-}\\
&=\int f^{+}\chi_{\bigcup_{n}E_{n}}-\int f^{-}\chi_{\bigcup_{n}E_{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n}\int f^{+}\chi_{E_{n}}-\lim_{n}\int f^{-}\chi_{E_{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n}\int(f^{+}-f^{-})\chi_{E_{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n}\int_{E_{n}}f
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't see OP mentioning that $f$ is integrable. So DCT cannot be applied.

Comment: When you split $f$ as $f^+$ and $f^-$, you get two different sequences that converge by the monotone convergence sequence. How do you know you can put them back together??? Can you please give me a few more details? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Look at the edited post now.

Comment: What would you use for the dominating function? Sorry, these details r so tough!!

Comment: The dominated one is simply $f\chi_{E_{1}}$ because $|f|\chi_{E_{n}}\leq |f|\chi_{E_{1}}$.

Comment: So you used monotone convergence to go from the third term to the fourth? How did you go to the 5th term to the 6th? Thanks btw!

Comment: From the second to third is due to Monotone, for the rest just the linearity of integral, and the fact that $\displaystyle\int_{A}f=\int f\chi_{A}$.